# ReactJS: Accessing Child Final State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This may seem as a bit of a redundant question but I'm trying to access the final state of a child in React, after it has updated. I've been looking into the React LifeCycle docs (I think that might be the issue, but not sure), searched high and low, and can't quite figure it out.

I've got a component which needs to access the (final) value of the state of a child, once that child has done some updating (AJAX request which then does a few `this.setStates`).

So far, I'm able to access the entire state of that child, accessing through a ref (Inside `componentDidMount`), but when I try to access a specific value of said state, it returns `null` or `undefined`.

Here's some example code to explain (I'll try to spare you as much useless code as possible):

```js
class Layout extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidMount(){ 
        // This gives me the updated State where pageTitle = "Whatever"
        console.log(this.refs.child1); 
        // However this gives me the initial State where pageTitle = null
        console.log(this.refs.child1.state.pageTitle);
    }
    render(){
        return (<div>
            {React.cloneElement(
                this.props.children,
                {ref: 'child1'}
            )}
        </div>);
    }
}
```

And here's the child component for reference (note: i'm using `axios` for my ajax requests):

```js
export class ChildComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            resultData: result,
            pageTitle: null
        }
    }
    componentDidMount(){
        this.serverRequest = axios.get(apiUrl)
            .then(function(result){
                this.setState({ 
                    resultData: result,
                    pageTitle: result.pageTitle
                }); 
            }.bind(this))
    }
    render(){
        return(<div>
            {use of different this.state.resultData values works fine here}
        </div>)
    }

}
```

Appreciate any help that comes this way

Comment: You should use callback function in your child props, and call it with your data when you get async result. In your parent you'll get thid data.

Comment: @Maxx Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

To use a callback, add this code to the parent element:

```
handleAsyncDone(data) {
    // Do whatever it is people do with data
}
```

And then pass that function to the child component, and in the childcomponent, add

```
this.props.handleAsyncDone(this.state);
```

Which will pass the child state back up to the parent.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I needed